# Intellij not recognizing source directory in project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Java EE. Maven.
Package `resources` marked as `Resource root`, package java as `Source root` also.
In my class I have path String `property\file.properties`, but when I run it, `IDEA` throws an exception :

> "java.io.FileNotFoundException: property\file.properties (The system
> cannot find the path specified)"

But when I change path String to `src\main\resources\property\file.properties` it works.
Packages marked as source. In Project File - Module I also see that this directories marked as source roots.
How can I fix it, any ideas?
I have already tried invalidate cache.
P.S: When I rename my string path with `shift + f6` file also change name.

EDIT:
[Source root packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A20CR.png)

Comment: Assuming it builds from the pom, close the project, delete all intellij files, then open the pom, rather than creating a project or opening the folder. If it doesn't build from the pom, make sure it does before you open it.

Comment: That's because when the project is build and you haven't changed anything in your pom.xml maven only takes resources from `src\main\resources` and copies them into the root of the created output (for example a jar file). So your `property\file.properties` is not included in it.

Answer (score 2):

In *IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate* as whereas the *Community Edition*, you can mark any **folder** in your project as your ***Sources, Tests, Resources, etc*** directory.

1. Right-click on your project root directory ➡ Select **Open Module Settings** in the context menu.
   [image: Open module settings]
2. In the **Project Structure** window that opens, choose a folder in your project ➡ then select to '*Mark*' that folder as your **Sources** or **Resources** directory depending on your needs.
   [image: mark folder as Sources directory]
3. You should see a list of marked folders in the right pane of the same window. Click the **Apply** and **OK** button when done to save your new changes.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, they have  already marked as source. Does not help =( (I`ve added picture of it)

Comment: What happens if i mark the root folder of a project as source? Because it's easier when there are too many src folder hidden in different paths